# Configuration could not be found in project when running ng test

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, karma-runner, angular6

I have just upgraded to Angular 6 but now our Jenkins build is failing.

It is running this command:

```
ng test -c karma.conf.cli.js
```

But the error is:

> Configuration 'karma.conf.cli.js' could not be found in project 'projectname'

However, the file in question exists in the root of the project. This command was running fine on Angular 5. Any ideas? Thanks

FYI I can reproduce the error by running the same command on the build server. We have also just upgraded Node.js to v8.11.2 (latest LTS)

Comment: which is the result if you run the same command manually?

Comment: exactly the same result

Comment: try to create a new angular 6 project to inspect what happens. it sounds really strange

Comment: I raised a GitHub bug report for this here ... https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11207

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the version 6 of Angular Cli the options for the commands has changed, instead use `-c`, you should use `--karma-config` or `--configuration`. You can see all options [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/test#options).

Comment: --karma-config looks very hopeful, +1 for trying, when I get round to working on this again I'll accept your answer if its correct - I'm sure it is correct - many thx

Answer (score 1):

I tried many and the one worked for me is as below. In your `angular.json` file add configuration section under test below.

```
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
         ....
      },
      "configurations": {  // this will hold a different configuration
        "jenkins": {
          "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.ci.js"
        }
      }
    },
```

And then while running the test use this configuration with `--configuration jenkins` options. So the final command will be

```
ng test --configuration jenkins
```

It will pick `karma.conf.ci.js` as configuration file as it set in the configuration section in angular cli configuration file and run unit test using that configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Jenkins after Angular 6 and I solved by replacing:

```
ng test --single-run --browsers ChromeHeadless -cc
```

with:

```
ng test --watch=false --browsers ChromeHeadless --code-coverage
```